# Automatically tag posts based on user-defined words

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugin-recommendation, tags

1. I want to systematically add tags (/custom taxonomy terms) to all previous posts, from a predefined set of tags (i.e., not Yahoo tags or tags from 3rd-party APIs).
2. For future posts, I would like tags to be either suggested or added based on the content of posts.
3. Ideally: I would like a more customized way of recommending/adding tags than simply looking for the tag text in an entry; ideally I'd be able to specify a set of related words (such as with a term meta field) so that, for example, a tag of `Education` is added not just when "education" appears in a post but when some of a specified list appear in the post: `teachers, school, standardized tests, math`, etc.

Can you recommend a plugin or strategy that would help achieve this?

I'm open to ideas both simple and complex.

Comment: I'm also open to arguments in support of Yahoo/3rd-party tag systems, which would allow me to use a plugin like Auto Tag Suggest [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-tag-suggest/] or Strictly Auto Tags [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/strictly-autotags/]

Comment: There is a plugin that can do exactly what you want, it is called [Automatic Post Tagger](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-post-tagger).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call myself an expert so test what I'm offering, but you may try to add a hook when you publish the post that uses a preg_match (or similar function) to find those terms in the post content. Then, based on what you found you could add the [wp_set_post_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms).